# Watch OS2 NSTimer problems

Tags: ios, xcode, nstimer, watchkit, watchos-2

I'm working on an App where I need to start a timer (using NSTimer) when the Watch is activated. With the Timer I asks some information to the iPhone (about every 1 seconds and maximum for 5 seconds). I'm using this to start the timer

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(myfunction) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

In the "myfunction" function, I restart the timer for the next time.

```
- (void) myfunction
{
   //Here I update a label text
   // [...]

   [timer invalidate];
   timer = nil;

   counter++;
   if(counter<5)
   {
     timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(myfunction) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
   }
}
```

My problem is that in the simulator all works fine but in a real watch (Watch-OS2 GM) the timer sometimes doesn't start or sometimes it starts but only for one time and after seems freeze! I see this because i Update a label in the watch at every elapsed period that shows a counter and I'm sure all is initialized in the "will activate" function. I don't understand why. Someone with the same issue?

Comment: Why create a new timer?  Why not keep count and invalidate the timer after the 5th invocation?

Comment: Sorry... you are right... I'm wrong when I paste the code... before counter++ I use  invalidate and timer=nil. I have correct the code

Comment: No my point is just do `if (counter > 5) { [timer invalidate]; timer = nil; }`.

Comment: In this case I have to use the repeats = true. But I don't want to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved with Watch OS 2.1. The problem was related to a quickly movement of the wrist: with the latest update of WatchOS all the timer are correctly restore after a quick move and all works fine

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/DesigningaWatchKitApp.html)

> Use your interface controller’s init and awakeWithContext: methods to
>   load any required data, set the values for any interface objects, and
>   prepare your interface to be displayed. Do not use the willActivate to
>   initialize your interface controller. The willActivate method is
>   called shortly before your interface is displayed onscreen, so you
>   should use that method only to make last-minute changes. For example,
>   you might also use that method to start animations or start other
>   tasks that should only happen while your interface is onscreen.

So, what method did you use to instantiate timer?

make sure you use  `willActivate` method and also use the `didDeactivate` method to clean up your interface and put it into a quiescent state. For example, use this method to invalidate timers and stop animations.

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried also to inizialize the timer also in the awakeWithContext, but I have the same issue. I use the didDeactivate to stop and clear the timer.